# In GIMP, how can I change one solid colors to multiple color variations?

Tags: color, gimp, texture, plugin

I'm not really sure how to ask this in words, but I used to use a program along time ago that would change one solid color into multiple variations. Say I have a solid red square, but I want it to be more textured, by varying the colors inside the square.

See this picture.

[image]

So what I am asking is, is there a method or brush to do this automatically, or possibly a gimp plugin? Google says no.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! That image is way too small to exemplify anything. Can you edit your question to include something bigger and more descriptive? Makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: What about HSV noise: http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-hsv-noise.html

Comment: I enlarged your image but hopefully I haven't confused the issue. It should be noted that the red squares were initially 3x3 pixel squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to work:

1. Create a blank 3 x 3 image (make bigger if you need more tones).
2. Put your color as foreground and paint the new image with **Bucket Fill.**
3. **Filters > Noise > RGB Noise** or **Filters > Noise > HSV Noise.**

If you find this size to be unmanageable, create something large, say 90 x 90 pixels, repeat the procedure increasing the noise levels, and then **Filters > Blur > Pixelise** with size 30 x 30. If you don't make the noise values quite large, the averaging of the pixelisation will give you little variation.

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in the [Grey's Magic for Image Computing (G'MIC)](https://gmic.eu/download.shtml) plugin for Gimp. In their collection of **Arrays & Tiles** plugins you will find the **Array [random colors]**.

[image]

- *Opacity:* controls the amount of variation induced by random colors.
- *X-tiles, Y-tiles:* control the number of resulting tiles (maximum 20).

In addition various color variation effects different to tiles are also included, e.g.:

[image]
Film grain
[image]
Random Gaussian noise degradation
[image]
Random color ellipses pattern

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Pixelize](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/C/plug-in-pixelize.html) feature, `Filters > Blur > Pixelize`

It works better on an photograph because it has more colors to pull from but you can repeat this effect to your liking to create more colors from its previously created or 'pixelized' colors.

[image]